# Multiple Where-Object Clauses with no effect

Tags: c#, powershell

I want to give out a list of people which are in different OUs throughout my company, but some OUs have to be left out. I tried to do that with the code shown below but it just keeps on displaying all people besides the admins

I tried to check if the clauses work if i just try them alone, leaving the other ones out for the moment. In that case also only the admins are left out, the other clauses wont show effect at all

I changed some things for data-protection.

```
$AdminOU = "OU=Admins,OU=Users,OU=Location,DC=company,DC=local"
$EXOU = "OU=Ex-workers,OU=Users,OU=Location,DC=company,DC=local"
$InactiveOU = "OU=deactivated,OU=aprenticeship,OU=Users,OU=Location,DC=company,DC=local"

$UsersWithDN = Get-ADUser -searchBase "$OUPath" -Filter * | 
    Where-Object {($_.distinguishedName -notlike "CN=*,$AdminOU") -and 
                  ($_.distinguishedName -notlike "CN=*,InactiveOU") -and 
                  ($_.distinguishedName -notlike "CN=*,EXOU")} | 
        Select-Object Samaccountname,distinguishedName
```

There are no errors popping up, I expect to get list in which admins,ex-workers and deactivated accounts are left out. However I'm only getting a list in which the admins are left out.

Comment: what do you see when you send ONE known-to-trigger-the-test object thru the `Where-Object`?

Comment: This is filtering for the exact string `"CN=*,InactiveOU"` or `"CN=*,EXOU"`. I suspect you wanted to use `"CN=*,$InactiveOU"` and `"CN=*,$EXOU"`

Comment: Your where-object conditions don't contain your variables. See `"CN=*,InactiveOU"` and `"CN=*,EXOU"`. You are missing the `$` on each.

Answer (score 2):

Is it because the matching criteria does not include a $ so the variable isn't referencing correctly? The first
`-notlike "CN=*,$AdminOU"` is correct, however the other two do not have `$` inside of the matching criteria i.e. `-notlike "CN=*,InactiveOU"` and `-notlike "CN=*,EXOU"`. 
Have you tried changing it to `"CN=*,$InactiveOU"` and `"CN=*,$EXOU"`? That should help.

Comment: That actually was the solution, I just forgot to put the $ infront. Thanks guys.